# Can AWS S3 detect uploads of malicious .exe files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can AWS S3 detect uploads of malicious .exe files?

What if we have an app that has an upload file function and files are uploaded to s3. What if attacker renames .exe file to .jpg file or insert a hidden file inside an image file (Steganography).

Is S3 capable of detecting this? or can this be done via bucket policy? if not, whats the solution you can recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Amazon S3 does not detect malicious files. However, there are 3rd party solutions for this. For example:

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B089QBV2GC

In addition, there are other security best practices too:

[Security Best Practices for Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/security-best-practices.html)

Comment: if s3 is capable to detect malicious files, why are there still 3rd party solutions? are there limitations in s3's ability to do it?

Comment: fixed the typo in my response.

Comment: @XmusJacksonFlaxonWaxon Think of Amazon S3 as a big disk drive. It just stores the data it is given. It does not do anything with the _contents_ of files.